# Lemma 1 in True Shape of Regret - Random variable being (sigma algebra)-measurable

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have been reading True Shape of Regret (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07182.pdf) but I have some doubts  regarding the assumptions of Lemma 1.

In Lemma 1 they assume to work in a measure space $(\Gamma, \mathcal{G})$, equipped with two distributions $\mathbb{P}_1, \mathbb{P}_2$. Later, they define a random variable $Z:\Omega\to[0,1]$, that is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

Does this mean that $\Omega \subset \Gamma$? Because for any $\omega \in \Omega$ we have that $\mathbb{E}[Z|G]=Z$, therefore $\omega \in \mathcal{G}$, and I assume that $\mathcal{G}$ is a sigma algebra of $\Gamma$.

Furthermore, in the proof, they define a set $E=\{(\gamma, x)\in \Gamma \times [0,1]: x\leq Z(\gamma)\}$, but $Z$ takes values on $\Omega$. So it looks like $\Gamma\subset \Omega$. Which contrasts what I said before. And later they integrate over $\Omega$ using the measures $\mathbb{P}_1$, $\mathbb{P}_2$ (which were defined on $\Gamma$).

Am I missing something trivial? Thank you very much for your time

Comment: My best _guess_ is that it was just very carelessly written, writing $\Gamma$ where $\Omega$ was meant and/or _vise versa_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I agree, I think this is a "typo" and $\Omega$ and $\Gamma$ are supposed to be the same.  I would suggest writing to the authors to confirm.